# How to arrange a string and assign it dataGridView or listview?

Tags: c#, listview, datagridview

I have a datagridview with three columns, one with auto generated buttons and others are values.

[image: DataGridView]

Now i need to store them into DB as a single value, and also to retrieve them back into another DataGridview.

I used stringbuilder but it stores value in a single string format, so i can't  retrieve them back.
Here is the codings...

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                sb.Append('<');
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {                        
                    sb.Append(dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col.Index].Value);
                    sb.Append('"');                        
                }
                sb.Append('>');
            }
            var invoice = sb.ToString();
```

the string is stored into DB in this order

> "WASH (S)"7""WAX (S)"10""GROOM (S)"6"

what i need is to get them back from DB and assign them to either list view or datagridview.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, actually you need to store only 2 values, namely Service and Price, right?
Create a string from the 2 column values, store in DB, and retrive breaking into 2 substrings at ")", what will give you back two values.

Comment: after retriving the string you might do sth like:

Answer (score 0):

After retriving one string from DB, say SP, you may do sth like this, to get back Service and Price values:

```
string Service = SP.Substring(0, SP.IndexOf(")")+1);
string Price = SP.Substring(SP.IndexOf(")")+1);
```

Comment: Not what i am looking for... do you even understand my question?

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite sure? You want to put all the data from the DataGridView into one string??? Using the second code you've shown, you can just append a string (not a string array you have, but one string!) row after row, excluding the first column (explicitely or using try.. catch sequence) adding a kind of marker at the end of row. After retriving from DB you split the string at the marker value to get rows, and later on split it once again, e.g. using the code I've shown to retrive the column values...

Comment: Why i need to get all the value into a single field is, because those are invoice of a bill. For every time when a bill is generated, this invoice list will be stored in the DB in a single field and then retrieved back when needed.

Comment: So, the steps I've written above, should probably suffice, right? Anyway, I would probably redesign the DB - apart from massive redudndancy, searching and retriving data will probabaly pose quite a quest... ;)

Comment: I figure how to get values from DataGridView and store as string[,], but i can't save it to DB, i am using MySQL any idea?

Comment: So, you have problems with

Comment: So, you have problems with getting data from DB or with splitting the retrived data or with feeding the data to datagridview?